# How to get count of multiple rows with distinct columns

Tags: sql

```
bldg | room#
 A   |  1
 A   |  2
 A   |  3
 B   |  1
 B   |  2
 B   |  3
 B   |  4
 C   |  1
 C   |  2
 C   |  3
```

I'm trying to figure out which bldg has a row count = to 3 and only 3.  For instance both A and C have a count of 3 , where B has a row count of 4.  So my result would be...

```
bldg
 A    
 C
```

I know I'm looking at a subquery with some sort of count(distinct bldg, room#)=3 but I can't figure it out.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple aggregation query with a `having` clause:

```
select bldg
from table t
group by bldg
having count(*) = 3;
```

Comment: I might suggest using `having count(distinct room) = 3` in the event they have multiple entries of the same bldg/room.

Comment: @user3543105 - don't use count(*) if you dont want to count nulls.

Comment: @bluefeet . . . Although the OP does include a `count(distinct)` as an example, the question also says:  "which bldg has a row count  . . .".  Just another ambiguously worded question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
select bldg
from tablez
group by bldg
having count(room) = 3
```